# Author and Book Classes A - An Array of Objects as an Instance Variable in java. Get the Array Objects attributes

Tags: java, arrays, object, oop

Been following this (https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3f_OOPExercises.html#zz-2.2) for study java OOP.
There is three java file. Now I tested `public Author getauthors() {return authors[0]}` will return the first author full into: name, email and gender.
**But I want iterate the authors array to get all the author name only.** what should I write in the *Books* java module?

1. One is pretty simple, used to describe `author` class. It have three attributes: `private String name;private String email;private String gender;`  the file already tested. All is fine.
2. The Book file to describe the book. One book can have multiple authors.

   public class Book {
   private String name;private int qty;
   private double price; Author authors[];

   ```
    public Book(String name, int qty, double price) {
        this.name = name; this.qty = qty; this.price = price;}
    public Book(String name, Author authors[], int qty, double price) {
        this.name = name; this.authors = authors;this.qty = qty; this.price = price;}

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public double getPrice() {return price;}
    public void setPrice(double price) {this.price = price;}
    public int getQty() {return qty;}
    public void setQty(int qty) {this.qty =qty;}
    public void setauthor(Author[] author) {this.authors = authors;}}
   ```
3. The third file to test all the methods coded in the first two file.

   ```
    public class testauthor {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            Author[] authorstest = new Author[2];
            authorstest[0] = new Author("Tan Ah Teck", "ahteck@nowhere.com", "m");
            authorstest[1] = new Author("Tyler Cowen", "tcowen@gmu.edu", "M");           
      Book dummyBook = new Book("small steps toward a much better world",authorstest, 19, 99);System.out.println(dummyBook.getName());}}
   ```

Comment: To me, it's not clear what exactly you are struggling with. Could you provide a little more detail? Do you want to print the names of all `Author` elements within an array?

Comment: Try my best to make the code readable....

Comment: @MCEmperor one book two author. 'public Author getauthors() {return authors[0]}'  can get me the first author info. But I want extract/get the book two  author's name. Author info is put in an array.

Comment: Use a `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) { author[i].getName(); }`, or shorter: `for (Author author : authors) { author.getName(); }`.

Comment: @MCEmperor `public Author getauthors() {return authors[0]}` this will work. the result is `name : Tan Ah Teck, gender : m, email : ahteck@nowhere.com `Since also the method need to return something. So I Still stuck.....

Comment: `public String[] getauthors() {String[] stringArray1; for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {stringArray1= authors[i].getName(); } return stringArray1;}`
The warning is  `C:\Users\JIAN HE\Desktop\myjava1>javac testauthor.java
.\Book.java:24: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]
        stringArray1= authors[i].getName(); }`
So far it's very close.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to return the names of all authors, you have to make a choice here:

- Either you return a `String[]`, where each element is the name of one of the authors;
- Or you return a `String`, where the authors are listed, say, with commas in between. For example: *`J. He, J. Skeet, M. C. Emperor`*.

  You could use a for loop for this:

  ```
  String authorsText = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
          authorsText += ", ";
      }
      authorsText += authors[i].getName();
  }
  ```

---

Further:

- It is a little peculiar that you can set a book's author after construction. Is the author of a book ever changed after the book is published? The same goes for a book's title. I would have removed those setters, as they don't make sense to me.

Comment: I thanks. So far I reached here. 
`public String[] getauthors() {String[] stringarray =  new String[authors.length]; System.out.println(authors.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {stringarray[i]=authors[i].getName();}
        return stringarray;} `
but the result is

`3
[Ljava.lang.String;@4617c264`
I do `import java.util.*;`

Comment: return a `String[]`  Can not print out. So I need to have a nested methods to print out all the elements. That would be too hard for me. Can you tell me how to use String[] ways to resolve the issue....

Comment: Well, [here's how to print out arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array). But you also seem to be missing some of the basics, like using a `for` loop, or the meaning of return types. I suggest you [study the basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html). I think that this tutorial provides a good understanding of Java.

Comment: I thank you. I finished W3C JAVA Tutorial. 
But I encountered another problem. I hope you can help me.....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580517/how-to-hold-the-value-from-the-userinput-in-java

Answer (score 0):

you can use **stream** to get all Names :

```
Arrays.stream(authors).map(a->a.getName()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

this get all names and separated by **coma**